# Fast lock implementation using pipes only

Tags: c, concurrency, locking, lock-free, c11

For fun I wanted to create a lock implementation that was about as fast as one using futexes but that used used pipes instead and that queues waiters in user space instead of in-kernel. For the queue the code uses an optimized version of the lock-free algorithm from Simple, Fast, and Practical Non-Blocking and Blocking Concurrent Queue Algorithms at http://www.cs.rochester.edu/research/synchronization/pseudocode/queues.html . I am not sure all the optimizations I have made are correct however. I also made some traditional implementations for comparison.

The lock interface is:

```
 /*
  * Copyright 2017 Steven Stewart-Gallus
  *
  * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  * You may obtain a copy of the License at
  *
  *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  *
  * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
  * implied.  See the License for the specific language governing
  * permissions and limitations under the License.
  */
 #ifndef LOCK_H
 #define LOCK_H

 struct lock;

 struct lock *lock_create(void);
 void lock_acquire(struct lock *lock);
 void lock_release(struct lock *lock);

 #endif
```

The test program is:

```
 /*
  * Copyright 2017 Steven Stewart-Gallus
  *
  * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  * You may obtain a copy of the License at
  *
  *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  *
  * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
  * implied.  See the License for the specific language governing
  * permissions and limitations under the License.
  */
 #define _GNU_SOURCE 1

 #include <errno.h>
 #include <pthread.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 #include "lock.h"

 #define PRODUCER_LOOP 1000000U
 #define NUM_THREADS 10U

 static void *contend(void * arg);

 int main()
 {
    struct lock *the_lock = lock_create();

    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    for (size_t ii = 0U; ii < NUM_THREADS; ++ii) {
        pthread_create(&threads[ii], NULL, contend, the_lock);
    }

    for (size_t ii = 0U; ii < NUM_THREADS; ++ii) {
        void *retval;
        pthread_join(threads[ii], &retval);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

The lock implementation is:

```
 /*
  * Copyright 2017 Steven Stewart-Gallus
  *
  * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  * You may obtain a copy of the License at
  *
  *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  *
  * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
  * implied.  See the License for the specific language governing
  * permissions and limitations under the License.
  */
 #define _GNU_SOURCE 1

 #include "lock.h"

 #include <errno.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <pthread.h>
 #include <stdatomic.h>
 #include <stdbool.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdint.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <sys/poll.h>
 #include <sys/eventfd.h>
 #include <xmmintrin.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 #if defined DO_FUTEX || defined PARTIAL_FUTEX
 #include <linux/futex.h>
 #include <sys/syscall.h>
 #endif

 #define NOTIFIER_FD_SPIN_LOOPS 40U
 #define FUTEX_SPIN_LOOPS 40U
 #define NOTIFIER_FUTEX_SPIN_LOOPS 20U
 #define NOOP_CONTEND_CYCLES 4U
 #define PAUSE_CONTEND_CYCLES 40U

 struct node;

 #define ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Alignas (16)

 #if defined RAW_EVENTFD
 struct event {
    int fd;
 };
 #elif defined DO_FUTEX
 struct event {
    ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(bool) spinning;
    ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(int) triggered;
 };
 #else
 struct event {
    ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(bool) triggered;
    ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(struct node *) head;
    ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(struct node *) tail;
    ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(uint64_t) head_contention;
    ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(uint64_t) tail_contention;
 };
 #endif
 static void event_init (struct event *event);
 static void event_wait (struct event *event);
 static void event_signal (struct event *event);

 #if defined NATIVE
 struct lock {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
 };
 #else
 struct lock {
    atomic_flag locked;
    struct event when_unlocked;
 };
 #endif

 #if defined NATIVE
 struct lock *lock_create(void)
 {
    struct lock *lock = aligned_alloc(_Alignof(struct lock), sizeof *lock);
    if (!lock)
        abort();
    pthread_mutex_init (&lock->mutex, 0);
    return lock;
 }
 void lock_acquire(struct lock *lock)
 {
    pthread_mutex_lock (&lock->mutex);
 }

 void lock_release(struct lock *lock)
 {
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&lock->mutex);
 }
 #else
 struct lock *lock_create(void)
 {
    struct lock *lock = aligned_alloc(_Alignof(struct lock), sizeof *lock);
    if (!lock)
        abort();
    atomic_flag_clear_explicit(&lock->locked, memory_order_relaxed);
    event_init (&lock->when_unlocked);
    return lock;
 }
 void lock_acquire(struct lock *lock)
 {
    for (;;) {
        if (!atomic_flag_test_and_set_explicit (&lock->locked, memory_order_acquire))
            break;

        event_wait (&lock->when_unlocked);
    }
 }

 void lock_release(struct lock *lock)
 {
    atomic_flag_clear_explicit (&lock->locked, memory_order_release);
    event_signal (&lock->when_unlocked);
 }
 #endif

 #if defined RAW_EVENTFD
 static void event_init (struct event *event) {
    if (-1 == (event->fd = eventfd(0, EFD_CLOEXEC | EFD_NONBLOCK)))
        abort();
 }

 static void event_wait (struct event *event) {
    {
        struct pollfd fds[1U] = {{ .fd = event->fd,
                       .events = POLLIN}};
        if (-1 == poll(fds, 1U, -1)) {
            abort();
        }
    }

    for (;;) {
        uint64_t xx;
        if (-1 == read(event->fd, &xx, sizeof xx)) {
            if (EAGAIN == errno)
                break;
            abort();
        }
    }
 }

 static void event_signal (struct event *event) {
    static uint64_t const one = 1U;
    if (-1 == write(event->fd, &one, sizeof one)) {
        if (errno != EAGAIN)
            abort();
    }
 }
 #elif defined DO_FUTEX
 static void event_init (struct event *event) {
    event->triggered = false;
    event->spinning = false;
 }

 static void event_wait (struct event *event) {
    for (;;) {
        atomic_store_explicit(&event->spinning, true, memory_order_release);

        atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);

        bool got_triggered = false;
        for (size_t ii = 0U; ii < NOTIFIER_FD_SPIN_LOOPS; ++ii) {
            got_triggered |= atomic_exchange_explicit(&event->triggered, false, memory_order_relaxed);
            if (got_triggered)
                break;
            _mm_pause();
        }
        atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acq_rel);
        atomic_store_explicit(&event->spinning, false, memory_order_release);
        if (got_triggered)
            break;
        if (atomic_exchange_explicit(&event->triggered, false, memory_order_acq_rel))
            break;

        syscall(__NR_futex, &event->triggered,
               FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL, NULL, 0);
    }
 }

 static void event_signal (struct event *event) {
    /* Already signaled */
    bool already_signaled = atomic_exchange_explicit (&event->triggered, 1, memory_order_acq_rel);
    bool still_spinning = atomic_load_explicit(&event->spinning, memory_order_acquire);

    if (already_signaled || still_spinning)
        return;

    syscall(__NR_futex, &event->triggered, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1, NULL, NULL, 0);
 }

 #else
 struct notifier;

 struct node {
    ALIGN_TO_CACHE struct notifier * trigger;
    ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(struct node *) next;
 };

 static ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(uint64_t) free_list_contention = 0U;
 static ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(struct node *) free_list = NULL;
 static ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(uint64_t) notifier_free_list_contention = 0U;
 static ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(struct notifier *) notifier_free_list = NULL;

 /* All used once so inline */
 static inline void enqueue (struct event *event, struct notifier *notifier);
 static inline struct notifier * dequeue (struct event *event);

 static inline struct node * allocate (void);
 static inline void deallocate (struct node *node);

 static inline struct notifier * allocate_notifier (void);
 static inline void deallocate_notifier (struct notifier *node);

 static inline void notifier_signal(struct notifier *notifier);
 static inline void notifier_wait(struct notifier *notifier);

 /* Very small so inline */
 static inline void on_failure(_Atomic(uint64_t) *contention);
 static inline void on_success(_Atomic(uint64_t) *contention);

 static void event_init (struct event *event) {
    struct node *n = aligned_alloc(_Alignof (struct node), sizeof *n);
    if (!n)
        abort();
    n->next = NULL;
    event->head = n;
    event->tail = n;
    event->head_contention = 0U;
    event->tail_contention = 0U;
 }

 static void event_wait (struct event *event) {
    if (atomic_exchange_explicit (&event->triggered, false, memory_order_acq_rel))
        return;

    struct notifier *notifier = allocate_notifier();

    enqueue (event, notifier);

    notifier_wait(notifier);

    deallocate_notifier (notifier);
 }

 static void event_signal (struct event *event) {
    atomic_store_explicit (&event->triggered, true, memory_order_release);

    struct notifier *notifier = dequeue (event);
    if (!notifier)
        return;

    notifier_signal(notifier);
 }

 static void *from(void *node)
 {
    return (void *)((uintptr_t)node & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFU);
 }

 static uint32_t tag(void *node)
 {
    return (uintptr_t)node >> 48U;
 }

 static void *to(void *node, uint32_t tag)
 {
    return (void *)((uintptr_t)node | (uint64_t)tag << 48U);
 }

 void enqueue (struct event *event, struct notifier *trigger)
 {
    struct node *tail;
    struct node *tail_again;
    struct node *next;

    struct node *node = allocate ();
    node->trigger = trigger;
    node->next = NULL;

    for (;;) {
        for (;;) {
            tail = atomic_load_explicit (&event->tail, memory_order_acquire);
            next = atomic_load_explicit (&((struct node*)from (tail))->next, memory_order_acquire);
            tail_again = atomic_load_explicit (&event->tail, memory_order_acquire);
            if (tail == tail_again)
                break;
            on_failure(&event->tail_contention);
        }
        on_success(&event->tail_contention);

        if (!from (next)) {
            if (atomic_compare_exchange_strong
                (&((struct node*)from (tail))->next,
                 &next,
                 to (node, tag (next) + 1U)))
                break;
        } else {
            atomic_compare_exchange_strong (&event->tail,
                         &tail,
                         to (from (next), tag (tail) + 1U));
        }
        on_failure(&event->tail_contention);
    }
    on_success(&event->tail_contention);
    atomic_compare_exchange_strong (&event->tail,
                 &tail,
                 to (node, tag (tail) + 1U));
 }

 static struct notifier * dequeue (struct event *event)
 {
    struct node *head;
    struct node *head_again;
    struct node *tail;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *dequeued;
    struct notifier *trigger;

    for (;;) {
        for (;;) {
            head = atomic_load_explicit (&event->head, memory_order_acquire);
            tail = atomic_load_explicit (&event->tail, memory_order_acquire);
            next = atomic_load_explicit (&((struct node *)from (head))->next,
                memory_order_acquire);
            head_again = atomic_load_explicit (&event->head, memory_order_acquire);
            if (head == head_again)
                break;
            on_failure(&event->head_contention);
        }
        on_success(&event->head_contention);

        if (from (head) == from (tail)) {
            if (!from (next)) {
                dequeued = NULL;
                trigger = NULL;
                break;
            }
            atomic_compare_exchange_strong
                (&event->tail,
                 &tail,
                 to (from (next), tag (tail) + 1U));
        } else {
            trigger = ((struct node *)from (next))->trigger;
            if (atomic_compare_exchange_strong (&event->head,
                             &head,
                             to (from (next), tag (head) + 1U))) {
                dequeued = from (head);
                break;
            }
        }
        on_failure(&event->head_contention);
    }
    on_success(&event->head_contention);

    if (dequeued) {
        deallocate (dequeued);
    }
    return trigger;
 }

 struct node * allocate (void)
 {
    struct node *head;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *n;

    for (;;) {
        head = atomic_load_explicit (&free_list, memory_order_relaxed);
        n = from (head);
        atomic_thread_fence (memory_order_acquire);
        if (!n) {
            on_success(&free_list_contention);
            n = aligned_alloc(_Alignof (struct node), sizeof *n);
            if (!n)
                abort();
            n->next = NULL;
            n->trigger = NULL;
            return n;
        }
        next = atomic_load_explicit (&n->next, memory_order_acquire);
        if (atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(&free_list,
                        &head,
                              to (from (next), tag (head) + 1U),
                              memory_order_acq_rel,
                              memory_order_acquire))
            break;
        on_failure(&free_list_contention);
    }
    on_success(&free_list_contention);
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
 }

 static void deallocate (struct node *node)
 {
    struct node *head;

    for (;;) {
        head = atomic_load_explicit (&free_list, memory_order_relaxed);
        node->next = to (from (head), 0);
        atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);
        if (atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit (&free_list,
                               &head,
                               to (node, tag (head) + 1U),
                               memory_order_acq_rel,
                               memory_order_acquire))
            break;
        on_failure(&free_list_contention);
    }
    on_success(&free_list_contention);
 }

 #if defined PARTIAL_FUTEX
 struct notifier {
    ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(bool) spinning;
    ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(int) triggered;
    ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(struct notifier *) next;
 };
 #else
 struct notifier {
    int fds[2U];
    ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(bool) spinning;
    ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(bool) triggered;
    ALIGN_TO_CACHE _Atomic(struct notifier *) next;
 };
 #endif

 struct notifier * allocate_notifier (void)
 {
    struct notifier *head;
    struct notifier *next;
    struct notifier *n;

    for (;;) {
        head = atomic_load_explicit (&notifier_free_list, memory_order_relaxed);
        n = from (head);
        atomic_thread_fence (memory_order_acquire);
        if (!n) {
            n = aligned_alloc(_Alignof (struct notifier), sizeof *n);
            if (!n)
                abort();

 #if !defined PARTIAL_FUTEX
 #if defined DO_EVENTFD
            int fd = eventfd(0, EFD_CLOEXEC | EFD_NONBLOCK);
            if (-1 == fd)
                abort();
            n->fds[0U] = fd;
            n->fds[1U] = fd;
 #else
            if (-1 == pipe2(n->fds, O_CLOEXEC | O_NONBLOCK))
                abort();
 #endif
 #endif

            n->spinning = false;
            n->triggered = false;
            n->next = NULL;
            return n;
        }
        next = atomic_load_explicit (&n->next, memory_order_acquire);
        if (atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(&notifier_free_list,
                        &head,
                              to (from (next), tag (head) + 1U),
                              memory_order_acq_rel,
                              memory_order_acquire))
            break;
        on_failure(&notifier_free_list_contention);
    }
    on_success(&notifier_free_list_contention);

    n->next = NULL;
    n->triggered = false;
    return n;
 }

 static void deallocate_notifier (struct notifier *node)
 {
    struct notifier *head;

    node->triggered = false;
    node->next = NULL;

    for (;;) {
        head = atomic_load_explicit (&notifier_free_list, memory_order_relaxed);
        node->next = to (from (head), 0);
        atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);
        if (atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit (&notifier_free_list,
                          &head,
                          to (node, tag (head) + 1U),
                          memory_order_acq_rel,
                          memory_order_acquire))
            break;
        on_failure(&notifier_free_list_contention);
    }
    on_success(&notifier_free_list_contention);
 }

 #if defined PARTIAL_FUTEX
 static inline void notifier_signal(struct notifier *notifier)
 {
    bool aleady_signaled = atomic_exchange_explicit(&notifier->triggered, true, memory_order_acq_rel);
    bool still_spinning = atomic_load_explicit(&notifier->spinning, memory_order_acquire);

    if (aleady_signaled || still_spinning)
        return;

    syscall(__NR_futex, &notifier->triggered, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1, NULL, NULL, 0);
 }

 static inline void notifier_wait(struct notifier *notifier)
 {
    for (;;) {
        atomic_store_explicit(&notifier->spinning, true, memory_order_release);

        atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);

        bool got_triggered = false;
        for (size_t ii = 0U; ii < NOTIFIER_FD_SPIN_LOOPS; ++ii) {
            got_triggered |= atomic_exchange_explicit(&notifier->triggered, false, memory_order_relaxed);
            if (got_triggered)
                break;
            _mm_pause();
        }
        atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acq_rel);
        atomic_store_explicit(&notifier->spinning, false, memory_order_release);
        if (got_triggered)
            break;
        if (atomic_exchange_explicit(&notifier->triggered, false, memory_order_acq_rel))
            break;

        syscall(__NR_futex, &notifier->triggered,
               FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL, NULL, 0);
    }
 }
 #else
 static inline void notifier_signal(struct notifier *notifier)
 {
    bool aleady_signaled = atomic_exchange_explicit(&notifier->triggered, true, memory_order_acq_rel);
    bool still_spinning = atomic_load_explicit(&notifier->spinning, memory_order_acquire);

    if (aleady_signaled || still_spinning)
        return;

    {
        static uint64_t const one = 1U;
        if (-1 == write(notifier->fds[1U], &one, sizeof one)) {
            if (errno != EAGAIN)
                abort();
        }
    }
 }

 static inline void notifier_wait(struct notifier *notifier)
 {
    for (;;) {
        atomic_store_explicit(&notifier->spinning, true, memory_order_release);

        atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);

        bool got_triggered = false;
        for (size_t ii = 0U; ii < NOTIFIER_FD_SPIN_LOOPS; ++ii) {
            got_triggered |= atomic_exchange_explicit(&notifier->triggered, false, memory_order_relaxed);
            if (got_triggered)
                break;
            _mm_pause();
        }
        atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acq_rel);
        atomic_store_explicit(&notifier->spinning, false, memory_order_release);
        if (got_triggered)
            break;
        if (atomic_exchange_explicit(&notifier->triggered, false, memory_order_acq_rel))
            break;

        {
            struct pollfd fds[1U] = {{ .fd = notifier->fds[0U],
                           .events = POLLIN}};
            if (-1 == poll(fds, 1U, -1)) {
                abort();
            }
        }

        for (;;) {
            uint64_t xx;
            if (-1 == read(notifier->fds[0U], &xx, sizeof xx)) {
                if (EAGAIN == errno)
                    break;
                abort();
            }
        }
    }
 }
 #endif

 static void on_failure(_Atomic(uint64_t) *contention)
 {
    uint64_t contention_count = atomic_load_explicit(contention, memory_order_relaxed);
    uint64_t next_count = contention_count + 1U;
    atomic_store_explicit(contention,
            contention_count < UINT64_MAX ?
             next_count : contention_count,
             memory_order_relaxed);

    if (contention_count < NOOP_CONTEND_CYCLES) {
        /* do nothing */
    } else if (contention_count < PAUSE_CONTEND_CYCLES) {
        _mm_pause();
    } else {
        sched_yield();
    }
 }

 static void on_success(_Atomic(uint64_t) *contention)
 {
    uint64_t contention_count = atomic_load_explicit(contention, memory_order_relaxed);
    uint64_t next_count = contention_count - 1U;
    atomic_store_explicit(contention,
            contention_count > 0U ?
             next_count : contention_count,
             memory_order_relaxed);
 }
 #endif

 static void *contend(void * arg)
 {
    struct lock *lock = arg;
    for (size_t ii = 0U; ii < PRODUCER_LOOP; ++ii) {
        lock_acquire(lock);
        /* Do nothing */
        lock_release(lock);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```